# JSON JavaScript

Tags: json

У меня есть такой массив json:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0:
  id: 1
  make: "Audi1"
  models: Array(3)
    0: {id: 1, model: "s8"}
    1: {id: 2, model: "s8"}
    2: {id: 3, model: "rs6"}
    length: 3
1:
  id: 2
  make: "BMW"
  models: Array(2)
    0: {id: 4, model: "m3"}
    1: {id: 5, model: "i8"}
    length: 2
length: 2
```

Как получить значение поля model?

Answer (score 1):

В `json` хранится массив объектов, бежим по ним

в каждом объекте бежим по `models` и получаем `model`.

```
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
  for(var j=0; j<list[i].models.length; j++) {
    console.log(list[i].models[j].model);
  }
}
```